# Getting 'unsupported method, fql.multiquery' when fetching data from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I'm trying to fetch data in my Android-App from Facebook via FQL multiquery like discribed here: http://www.kanatorn.info/2011/12/31/fql-multiple-query-android-sdk-example/

here's my code:

```
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        JSONObject multiquery = new JSONObject();
        try {
            multiquery.put("query1", "SELECT eid, name, start_time, is_date_only, pic_square, pic_big, location FROM event WHERE eid IN" + 
                "(SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid=me() AND start_time >= now()) ORDER BY start_time");
            multiquery.put("query2", "SELECT eid, rsvp_status, start_time FROM event_member WHERE uid=me() AND start_time >= now() ORDER BY start_time");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        params.putString("method", "fql.multiquery");
        params.putString("queries", multiquery.toString());         

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        Request request = new Request(session,
            "/fql",
            params,
            HttpMethod.GET,                 
            new Request.Callback(){
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    ...
                }
            });             
        Request.executeAndWait(request);
```

the result I'm getting is the following:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 500, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 500, errorCode: -1, errorType: Exception, errorMessage: Unsupported method, fql.multiquery}, isFromCache:false}
```

I can't figure out where my mistake is. It says `unsupported method, multiquery`, but this actually should be a valid method, right? I looked everywhere for a similiar problem but it seems that I'm alone with that issue.
I have the feeling that I'm missing something simple...
Would be cool if someone can help me out. Thanks!

btw. with normal queries everything works fine.

Comment: have you read this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/run-fql-queries/

Comment: oh man, I googled everything and looked (oviously almost) everywhere on the fb-developers page but never stumbled over that link. thank you so much. that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer accept and will close this stack

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve this
have you read this developers page.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/run-fql-queries/

Updated url

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/#fql

Answer (score 0):

The linked Kanatorn page says `method` should be `fql.multiquery`, but you have just `multiquery`.

Comment: oops... copy/pasted it wrong. I edited the main question. I originally typed fql.multiquery as method. still not working...